# Cannot start spyder

Tags: spyder

@CarlosCordoba I cannot start spyder `An error occurred while starting the kernel` any thoughts please

```
"[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anconda\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
File "C:\Anconda\lib\site‑packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 32, in run
return loop.run_until_complete(future)
File "C:\Anconda\lib\site‑packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 60, in run_until_complete
f = asyncio.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
File "C:\Anconda\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 684, in ensure_future
raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have tried re-installing with below command, but that didn't work for me:

```
conda remove spyder 
conda remove python-language-server
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.1.5
```

Comment: @CarlosCordoba can you please advice.

Comment: Have you read the [Spyder Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ)? What steps did you try to resolve this issue? What version of Spyder are you running? What OS? How did you install Spyder?

Comment: This issue started after upgrading to 5.1.5. seem it is quite buggy. Tried these and nothing works.. conda remove spyder
conda remove python-language-server
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.1.5

Comment: 5.1.5 works without a problem for me, so it's seems a bit harsh to tag it as "quite buggy" if it doesn't work for you. Did you try [other troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ#recommended-troubleshooting-steps)? Resetting Spyder has helped me in the past, have you tried that?

Comment: And while you've been here for quite some years already, it might still be good to take the [tour] as it might help you create answerable questions and make your experience here better overall.

Comment: Yes if u see my above steps i did reset and complete re-install etc., and nothing works for me. Can you please advise what steps have u done when u get these errors to resolve this??

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your steps that you did a [reset of Spyder](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-reset-prefs). Did you read [the troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ#recommended-troubleshooting-steps)? If not, please do and try the steps described there.